# What is the physical interpretation of "internal pressure"?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

> $$ \require{begingroup}
> \begingroup
> \newcommand{\md}[0]{\mathrm{d}} \md U = \pi_T\,\md V + C_V \,\md T$$
>   where  $\pi_T$ is the internal pressure and is given by $\displaystyle {\left(\partial U \over \partial V\right)_T}$.

---

- What does the internal pressure actually physically mean? I can see it is the slope of the $U$-$V$ graph at constant temperature but that does not clear things up.
- Also why is this quantity called the internal pressure and not something else? $\endgroup$

Comment: I'd assume that the phrase is trying to acknowledge the wall effect. Pressure at the wall of the container isn't the same as pressure away from the wall.

Comment: @MaxW Outside the container or inside the conatiner ?

Comment: Inside of course. what would the pressure outside of the container have to do with anything?

Comment: I also thought that but I did not understand where that pressure will be acting ?  on other molecules ?

Comment: I don't understand your last remark. Could you please clarify what "that pressure" is?

Comment: @MaxW I am really sorry. The pressure that is away from the wall.

Comment: Let's look at it this way. I am on the starship Enterprise and contain a 1 meter sphere of gas in a force field. I then beam the sphere into deep space and then release the force field. What happens? The gas dissipates in a spherical direction since there is nothing pushing the gas back together.

Comment: @MaxW So that force field is internal pressure ?

Comment: No, the force field acts against the internal pressure.

Comment: @MaxW Yes sorry, my mistake I thought the force field is inside the sphere of gas, whereas it is the exact opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [orthocresol's](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/16683/orthocresol) derivation of an internal pressure $\pi_T$ relation $(1)$ [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/59356/27806).

$$\pi_T = T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V - P\tag{1}$$

---

Internal pressure $\pi_T$ measures what you would expect from its definition:

$$\pi_T \equiv \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T.$$

It shows *how internal energy changes when volume is changed and temperature is constant*. For ideal gases the [change is zero](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/59356/27806), something that also follows from the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Ideal_gas_law).

$$\mathrm{d}U_{\text{ideal gas}}= \frac{\nu}{2}nR\mathrm{d}T \implies \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T = 0 \ \  \text{for an ideal gas}$$

In other words, the total energy an ideal gas has is not dependent on volume. There is no repulsion nor attraction amongst ideal gas particles.

As a first approximation to model real gases, the [van der Waals equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation#Derivation) $(2)$ is used.

$$\left(P+a\frac{n^2}{V^2}\right)\left(V-nb\right)=nRT\tag{2}$$

Hence,

$$P = \frac{nRT}{V-nb} - a\frac{n^2}{V^2}\tag{3}.$$

Using relations $(1)$ and $(3)$

$$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V = \frac{nR}{V-nb} \overset{(3)}{=} \frac{1}{T}\left(P + a\frac{n^2}{V^2}\right).$$

Again via formula $(1)$

$$\pi_T = T \cdot \overbrace{\frac{1}{T}\left(P + a\frac{n^2}{V^2}\right)}^{(\partial P/\partial T)_V} - P = a\frac{n^2}{V^2}\tag{4}.$$

Result $(4)$ $\pi_T = a\frac{n^2}{V^2}$ demonstrates that for real gases internal energy will change when volume is decreased or increased. Real particles have interparticular forces that vary with distance. A hint as to why $\pi_T$ is called *internal pressure* will be given when $(4)$ is substituted into $(2)$:

$$\left(P+\pi_T\right)\left(V-nb\right)=nRT,$$

or even better, $(3)$:

$$P = \frac{nRT}{V-nb} - \pi_T.$$

- If $\pi_T > 0,$ then $P$ will be smaller. Therefore, attractive forces are dominant.
- If $\pi_T < 0,$ then $P$ will be bigger. Therefore, repulsive forces are dominant.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking about. I think question is more about why "internal pressure" vs. just "pressure." In other words what does "internal" add?

Comment: @MaxW I did always think about it as 'a correction to pressure that derives from *inter*molecular forces'. As opposed to traditional (ideal gas) pressure which can be modelled as collisions with container walls. To recap, real gases occupy a finite volume, and if one decreases the volume of the system (via an *external pressure*), the molecules are forced more close together. How these particles respond is what *internal pressure* measures. This is, in turn, to be differentiated from the traditional pressure (of which internal pressure is a component).

Comment: @MaxW Whether this is a good way of thinking about it, remains to be seen. :=) (Feel free to downvote accordingly if this is wrong.)

Comment: @LinearChristmas Wow, this is easily one of the most complete answers I have ever got. Crystal clear. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That is pretty much the significance of $\pi_T$, it is a measure of intermolecular (IM) forces. As V changes, the average IM distance will change, and then the difference in the IM potential energy will affect U. For an ideal gas, there are no IM forces; hence there's no effect on U and $\pi_T = 0$. (And I realise I am just repeating what you said... whoops)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the gas is enclosed in a cylinder with a movable piston but the piston is *not* moving now. If the piston - wall interface is frictionless then the *internal* pressure (the one you are asking about) is the same as the external pressure (the one that can be controlled by mechanical means, e.g., by pushing or pulling on it.) If there is no friction and the process is reversible then the internal pressure is equal to the eternal pressure (the control variable) and is a state variable one that can be described by some other equilibrium parameters, such as $U$ or $T$ or $V$. If there is friction between the piston and the wall then depending on whether one pushes the piston in or pulls it out the internal pressure maybe larger or smaller than the external one and there is no such functional relationship among these parameters.